# How to check if Kik/Snapchat Usernames are valid/exists with PHP

Tags: validation, kik, snapchat

I need to check from a Website / Webhosting(no vps) if a kik and snapchat username exists / is valid?

I have no Idea how to do that since these are only mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

I found this URL:

https://feelinsonice-hrd.appspot.com/web/deeplink/snapcode?username=joshconstine&type=SVG

If there is a `<image clip-path="url(#clip)"` in there, then it sure is a valid snapchat username.