# How to check if a Snapchat account exists?

Tags: java, validation, snapchat

I am building an app on both android and ios & I am asking users to enter their Snapchat accounts. I don't want people to add fake snapchat accounts so I searched around and could not find a way.

I only found this answer [How to check if Kik/Snapchat Usernames are valid/exists with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094768/how-to-check-if-kik-snapchat-usernames-are-valid-exists-with-php)
but people who did not create their face emoji will not have what the answer suggested.

Please if someone can think of a way or have the answer I will be thankful.

thanks

Comment: I would not be surprised if this were intentionally unavailable for security reasons.

Comment: You'll probably want to use an API. As far as I can tell, SnapChat doesn't really support integration of their app. There are some third-party, open-source ones available like here: https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap

Comment: yes I know there is no API.. but I though maybe someone found a smart way to check that... thanks guys @Malphrush and JOE

Answer (score 2):

Since Snapchat doesn't have a public developer API, I don't believe you can check beforehand whether an account exists. I suppose you could try snapping the user a confirmation code to confirm their identity but I doubt that's really ideal for what you want to do.